# VBA-shape with realtive positioning

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code but it's not working as I want it. 
This is what I want:
-if I write something in cell A1,A2 or A3 (in worksheet1) a textbox is created in worksheet(2). This works but now I want the place of the textbox to change when I right in cell B1,B2,B3. 
I tried to do that with the code below, but I think there might be a problem with the way I defined the `Range("B" & CStr(i))` because when I use just B1 it works.
I need to change the code two do two things differently:
1- If I write in B1 "cliente" I want the texbox with the text from A1 to be created in toppos=150 and if I change it to "financeiro" I want the texbox to be created in toppos=20.

2- If B1 and B2 have "fianceiro" written I want the textboxes related to A1 and A2 to be next to each other.
Can someone help me?
Thank you

So this is what I want:
-Textboxes created with the content of cells A1 to A3 on worksheet 2;
-If I change the content the content of the textbox should be updated, if I erase the value then the textbox should be deleted;
-the position of the textboxes should change with the options I choose in column B. I want the worksheet(2) to have 4 "slices", the first is for the option "financeiro", so all the textboxes related to that slice of page should be in a specific place in the worksheet, for example, in position 20, if on the other hand that textbox is from the option "cliente", the textbox should be in the slice related to "cliente", position 150.
-also each option in column B might have more then one textbox so I want the textboxes from the same option to appear side by side.

[image: Worksheet(1)]

[image: RealWorksheet(2)]

[image: idealWorksheet(2)]

---

```
Sub removercaixas(strName As String)
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In Worksheets(2).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoTextBox And shp.Name = strName Then shp.Delete
    Next shp
End Sub

Sub criarcaixastexto(strName As String)
    Dim wsActive As Worksheet
    Dim box As Shape

    Set wsActive = Worksheets(2)

    Dim leftpos As Long
    Dim toppos As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 3

        If Worksheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(i)).Value = "financeiro" Then
            toppos = 20
        ElseIf Worksheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(i)).Value = "cliente" Then
            toppos = 150
        ElseIf Worksheets(1).Range("B" & CStr(i)).Value = "processos internos" Then
            toppos = 250
        Else:
            toppos = 350
        End If
    Next i

    Select Case strName
        Case Is = "$A$1"
            leftpos = 50
        Case Is = "$A$2"
            leftpos = 200
        Case Is = "$A$3"
            leftpos = 350

    End Select

    Set box = wsActive.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, leftpos, toppos, 100, 50)
    box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Worksheets(1).Range(strName).Value
    box.Name = strName
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$A$1", "$A$2", "$A$3"
            removercaixas (Target.Address)
            If Len(Target) > 0 Then criarcaixastexto (Target.Address)
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I just updated my answer.  It was pretty hard for me to discern exactly what you what to do.  You might want  to edit your question, putting your goals in a list form.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of some of the OP's logic or exactly what he wants to accomplish.  Instead of adding and removing textboxes, I would create a Function that would create the textbox, if needed, and return a reference to it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Count > 1 Or Not Sh.Index = 1 Or Len(Target) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim box As Shape

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B3")) Is Nothing Then
        Set box = getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Offset(0, -1).Address)
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case Is = "financeiro"
                box.Top = 20
            Case Is = "cliente"
                box.Top = 150
            Case Is = "processos internos"
                box.Top = 250
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim box As Shape
    If Target.Count > 1 Or Not Sh.Index = 1 Or Len(Target) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then
        Set box = getCaixas(Worksheets(2), Target.Address)
        Select Case Target.Address
            Case Is = "$A$1"
                box.Left = 50
            Case Is = "$A$2"
                box.Left = 200
            Case Is = "$A$3"
                box.Left = 350
        End Select
        box.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub

Function getCaixas(ws As Worksheet, CaixasName As String) As Shape
    Dim box As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set box = ws.Shapes(CaixasName)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set box = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 100, 50)
        box.Name = CaixasName
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set getCaixas = box
End Function
```

Comment: you have two workbook change events and I converted them to just one. And it works, but your code doesn't delete the texboxes when I delete the values in A1...

Comment: My code has a `Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick` event  and a `Workbook_SheetChange° event.  As stated I didn t see any reason to delete the textboxes. You can use `getCaixas.Delete`.

Comment: I added the `Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick` event because I thought that is what you implied when you said   "when I right in cell B1,B2,".  I'm guessing "right" should be "write"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, you're totatlly right. Can you please edit your code to include the getCaixas.delete? I tried it but then the if related to the range("B1:B3") doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I have a busy weekend ahead of me